# Can't install QML.jl with Flux.jl present

Tags: julia

On trying to install QML I get:

```
(Tibra.jl) pkg> add QML
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Flux [587475ba]:
 Flux [587475ba] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.4.1-0.12.9 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.4.1-0.12.9
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Requires [ae029012] to versions: 0.8.3-0.12.9 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.8.3-0.12.9
 │ └─Requires [ae029012] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.5.0-1.3.0 or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with QML [2db162a6] to versions: 1.0.0-1.3.0
 │     └─QML [2db162a6] log:
 │       ├─possible versions are: 0.6.0-0.7.0 or uninstalled
 │       └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.6.0-0.7.0
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with CUDAapi [3895d2a7] to versions: [0.4.1-0.8.3, 0.10.0-0.12.9] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.8.3, 0.10.0-0.12.9]
 │ └─CUDAapi [3895d2a7] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.5.0-4.0.0 or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with CuArrays [3a865a2d] to versions: [0.4.1-0.8.3, 0.11.0-0.12.9] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.8.3, 0.11.0-0.12.9]
 │ └─CuArrays [3a865a2d] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.2.1-2.2.2 or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with NNlib [872c559c] to versions: 0.8.3-0.11.6 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.8.3, 0.11.0-0.11.6]
 │ └─NNlib [872c559c] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.3.2-0.8.0 or uninstalled
 │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Flux [587475ba] to versions: 0.3.2-0.8.0
 │   │ └─Flux [587475ba] log: see above
 │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Requires [ae029012] to versions: 0.6.0-0.8.0 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.6.0-0.8.0
 │   │ └─Requires [ae029012] log: see above
 │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Compat [34da2185] to versions: [0.3.2-0.7.6, 0.7.10-0.7.11] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.6.0-0.7.6, 0.7.10-0.7.11]
 │   │ └─Compat [34da2185] log:
 │   │   ├─possible versions are: 1.0.0-3.41.0 or uninstalled
 │   │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with TerminalMenus [dc548174] to versions: 1.0.0-2.2.1
 │   │     └─TerminalMenus [dc548174] log:
 │   │       ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0 or uninstalled
 │   │       └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.1.0
 │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with LoopVectorization [bdcacae8] to versions: [0.3.2-0.7.1, 0.7.4-0.8.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [0.6.0-0.7.1, 0.7.4-0.7.6, 0.7.10-0.7.11]
 │     └─LoopVectorization [bdcacae8] log:
 │       ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-0.12.101 or uninstalled
 │       └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 0.9.0-0.12.101 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with CUDA [052768ef] to versions: [0.4.1-0.10.4, 0.12.2-0.12.9] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.8.3
 │ └─CUDA [052768ef] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-3.8.0 or uninstalled
 │   ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [2.3.0, 2.5.0-3.8.0] or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with LLVM [929cbde3] to versions: 3.3.3-3.8.0 or uninstalled
 │     └─LLVM [929cbde3] log:
 │       ├─possible versions are: 0.9.0-4.7.1 or uninstalled
 │       └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 4.0.0-4.7.1 or uninstalled
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Colors [5ae59095] to versions: 0.10.4-0.12.9 or uninstalled — no versions left
   └─Colors [5ae59095] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.9.0-0.12.8 or uninstalled
     ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Flux [587475ba] to versions: 0.9.0-0.12.8
     │ └─Flux [587475ba] log: see above
     └─restricted by compatibility requirements with ColorTypes [3da002f7] to versions: 0.12.0-0.12.8 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.12.0-0.12.8
       └─ColorTypes [3da002f7] log:
         ├─possible versions are: 0.7.0-0.11.0 or uninstalled
         └─restricted by compatibility requirements with QML [2db162a6] to versions: 0.10.0-0.11.0
       
    └─QML [2db162a6] log: see above
```

Project.toml

```
[deps]
BenchmarkTools = "6e4b80f9-dd63-53aa-95a3-0cdb28fa8baf"
CodecZstd = "6b39b394-51ab-5f42-8807-6242bab2b4c2"
DataStructures = "864edb3b-99cc-5e75-8d2d-829cb0a9cfe8"
Distributions = "31c24e10-a181-5473-b8eb-7969acd0382f"
FlatBuffers = "53afe959-3a16-52fa-a8da-cf864710bae9"
Flux = "587475ba-b771-5e3f-ad9e-33799f191a9c"
GR = "28b8d3ca-fb5f-59d9-8090-bfdbd6d07a71"
GZip = "92fee26a-97fe-5a0c-ad85-20a5f3185b63"
Gtk = "4c0ca9eb-093a-5379-98c5-f87ac0bbbf44"
HDF5 = "f67ccb44-e63f-5c2f-98bd-6dc0ccc4ba2f"
Match = "7eb4fadd-790c-5f42-8a69-bfa0b872bfbf"
Parameters = "d96e819e-fc66-5662-9728-84c9c7592b0a"
Plotly = "58dd65bb-95f3-509e-9936-c39a10fdeae7"
PlotlyJS = "f0f68f2c-4968-5e81-91da-67840de0976a"
Plots = "91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80"
ShiftedArrays = "1277b4bf-5013-50f5-be3d-901d8477a67a"
StatsFuns = "4c63d2b9-4356-54db-8cca-17b64c39e42c"
TerminalMenus = "dc548174-15c3-5faf-af27-7997cfbde655"
TimeZones = "f269a46b-ccf7-5d73-abea-4c690281aa53"
```

If I try what cbk suggested, I get an install error saying to precompile.  This is the result:

```
Precompiling project...
  ✗ QML
  13 dependencies successfully precompiled in 8 seconds (99 already precompiled)
  1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the package

julia> using QML
[ Info: Precompiling QML [2db162a6-7e43-52c3-8d84-290c1c42d82a]
WARNING: import of ColorTypes.include into QML conflicts with an existing identifier; ignored.
C++ exception while wrapping module QML: invalid subtyping in definition of QObject with supertype Any

signal (11): Segmentation fault: 11
in expression starting at none:0
gc_sweep_pool at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
_jl_gc_collect at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_gc_collect at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_gc_pool_alloc at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_gc_alloc at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
_new_array_ at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
_new_array at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_alloc_array_1d at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
Array at ./boot.jl:457 [inlined]
Array at ./boot.jl:476 [inlined]
getindex at ./array.jl:411 [inlined]
BasicBlock at ./compiler/ssair/basicblock.jl:25 [inlined]
compute_basic_blocks at ./compiler/ssair/ir.jl:91
convert_to_ircode at ./compiler/optimize.jl:395
run_passes at ./compiler/optimize.jl:302
optimize at ./compiler/optimize.jl:296 [inlined]
_typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:255
typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_edge at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:823 [inlined]
abstract_call_method at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:504
abstract_call_gf_by_type at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:105
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1342
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_apply at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:987
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1249
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1382
abstract_eval_statement at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1534
typeinf_local at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1918
typeinf_nocycle at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:2014
_typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:226
typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_edge at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:823 [inlined]
abstract_call_method at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:504
abstract_call_gf_by_type at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:105
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1342
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_apply at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:987
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1249
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1382
abstract_eval_statement at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1534
typeinf_local at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1918
typeinf_nocycle at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:2014
_typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:226
typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_edge at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:823 [inlined]
abstract_call_method at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:504
abstract_call_gf_by_type at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:105
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1342
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_apply at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:987
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1249
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1382
abstract_eval_statement at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1534
typeinf_local at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1918
typeinf_nocycle at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:2014
_typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:226
typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_edge at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:823 [inlined]
abstract_call_method at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:504
abstract_call_gf_by_type at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:105
abstract_call_known at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1342
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1397
abstract_call at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1382
abstract_eval_statement at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1534
typeinf_local at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:1918
typeinf_nocycle at ./compiler/abstractinterpretation.jl:2014
_typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:226
typeinf at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_ext at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:909
typeinf_ext_toplevel at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:942
typeinf_ext_toplevel at ./compiler/typeinfer.jl:938
jfptr_typeinf_ext_toplevel_14931 at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib (unknown line)
jl_apply_generic at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_type_infer at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_generate_fptr at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_compile_method_internal at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_apply_generic at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
display_error at ./client.jl:107
unknown function (ip: 0x10f320332)
jl_apply_generic at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_f__call_latest at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
#invokelatest#2 at ./essentials.jl:716 [inlined]
invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:714 [inlined]
_start at ./client.jl:497
jl_sysimg_fvars_base at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib (unknown line)
jl_apply_generic at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
true_main at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_repl_entrypoint at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 3085738 (Pool: 3084551; Big: 1187); GC: 1

signal (11): Segmentation fault: 11
in expression starting at none:0
gc_sweep_pool at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
_jl_gc_collect at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_gc_collect at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_gc_pool_alloc at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_gc_alloc at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_push_excstack at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
throw_internal at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
jl_sig_throw at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 21788740 (Pool: 21781964; Big: 6776); GC: 1
ERROR: Failed to precompile QML [2db162a6-7e43-52c3-8d84-290c1c42d82a] to /Users/bryan/.julia/compiled/v1.7/QML/jl_lRw54M.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
 [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
 [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
 [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
 [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:997
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is indirect, since I cannot reproduce it in a clean environment. Try:

```
] 
activate --temp
add QML
add Flux
```

where the `]` is to enter the `pkg>` REPL mode

Comment: It installs with an error and says to run precompile.  Added results to issue.